XFC0045 Binding: Property "Title" not found on "EcoTracker.ViewModels.UserProfileViewModel"
I use the ViewModel to display user information and posts on the profile page, but I get an error when trying to get these posts from the UserPosts collection
ContentPage.xaml:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:EcoTracker.ViewModels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:EcoTracker.Converters" 
             x:DataType="viewModels:UserProfileViewModel"
             Title="Мой профиль"
             x:Class="EcoTracker.Views.UserProfilePage">
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
       <Image Source="{Binding User.Avatar}" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
<ListView x:Name="UserPostsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding UserPosts}" HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="10" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="15">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" />
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

ContentPage.xaml.cs:
public partial class UserProfilePage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly UserProfileViewModel viewModel;

    public UserProfilePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new UserProfileViewModel();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await viewModel.LoadUserDataAndPostsAsync();
    }
}

ViewModel:
 public class UserProfileViewModel
 {
     private UserData _user;
     public UserData User
     {
         get { return _user; }
         set
         {
             _user = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(User));
         }
     }

     private ObservableCollection<UserPostModel> _userPosts;
     public ObservableCollection<UserPostModel> UserPosts
     {
         get { return _userPosts; }
         set
         {
             _userPosts = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UserPosts));
         }
     }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
     {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }

     public async Task LoadUserDataAndPostsAsync()
     {
         User = UserDataHolder.GetUserData();
         int userId = User.Id;
         UserPosts = new ObservableCollection<UserPostModel>(await GetUserPostsAsync(userId));
         if (User == null)
         {
             User = new UserData();
         }

         int followersCount = await GetFollowersCountAsync(userId);
         if (followersCount >= 0)
         {
             User.FollowersCount = followersCount;
         }

         int followingCount = await GetFollowingCountAsync(userId);
         if (followingCount >= 0)
         {
             User.FollowingCount = followingCount;
         }
     }
}

I saw the decision to delete the DataType, then the error disappears, but neither user data nor post data are displayed on the page

This is not a complete code, I inserted the main one, since the site restricts

you need to add a DataType to your template
<DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:UserPostModel">

you may also need to use a different xmlns depending on how your code is structured

I don't have vm UserPosts, I have vm UserProfileViewModel, which contains methods for getting user data and getting his posts

typo, it should be UserPostModel

Now everything is fine with the bindings, but the data of the user and his posts are not displayed, what could this be related to?

have you debugged your VM to be sure the data is loaded correctly?

I noticed such a thing that when I launch the application, nothing is displayed, but if I delete the property in xaml and write it again, everything will be fine, how can I fix it?

try disabling Hot Reload
